# Multiple queues to publish in MassTransit and RabbitMQ in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to coding a system where we have a queue to process messages. The problem is that I want to have two queues: one for develop environment and another for production environment.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(c =>
{
    c.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
    {
        configurator.Host(builder.Configuration["EventBusSettings:HostAddress"]);
    });
});
```

**PublishController**

```
PublishAssetRequest publishAssetRequest = new(){ 
                    AssetId = asset.Id, 
                    ApplicationId = createAssetRequest.ApplicationId 
                };
                
                await _publishEndpoint.Publish(publishAssetRequest);
```

I know that if I want to specify what queue I want to use in consumer is that way:

**Consumer**

```
busFactoryConfigurator.ReceiveEndpoint(**configuration["EventBusSettings:Queue"]** ?? string.Empty, c =>
                        {
                            c.ConfigureConsumer<BlockchainConsumer<PublishAssetRequest>>(context);
                            c.ConfigureConsumer<BlockchainConsumer<PublishAssetMetadataRequest>(context);
                        });
```

The problem is that I want to do the same with the publisher.

I would like to be able to specify what queue I want to use to publish (send to a queue) but I didn't find any way to do that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RabbitMQ, I would suggest creating separate virtual hosts for each environment (instead of sharing a single virtual host with multiple environments). It's easy to do with CloudAMQP, or even just running your own RabbitMQ broker.

Comment: I will create another virtual host for development environment. Thanks Chris.